# didnot write in excel sheet

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

i want to write my data in excel.but it didnot write in formatted way

```
driver.get("https://careernavigator.naukri.com/sales-executive-retail-careers-in-mahindra-and-mahindra-financial-services-15731");
List<WebElement> row = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='rect' and @height='40']"));
        List<WebElement> column = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and (@dy=4 or @dy='3.5')]"));
         for (int i=0;i<column.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(column.get(i).getText());
            XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(i);
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++) 
            {
                Cell cell1 = row1.createCell(j);    
                cell1.setCellValue(column.get(j).getText());
```

Comment: what is formatted way? what is the expected result?

Comment: this one is link https://careernavigator.naukri.com/sales-executive-retail-careers-in-mahindra-and-mahindra-financial-services-15731 here top campy list,acg exp,avg sal,in lakhs is there..that one is the expected result

Comment: I see the link and the xpaths you are using, it looks OK. I'm trying to understand if the issue is with the elements locator or with the Excel sheet ?

Comment: k.plz try.....sir

Comment: Can you please share the output coming from System.out.println(column.get(i).getText()); Also, maybe explain the logic of the switch from i to j?

Comment: i is for no. of rows..j is the text value

Comment: so column.get(j) seems to be getting text unrelated to the row you were specifiying? It feels like you need to be getting text for j=0 to 3 within column.get(i). This would be easier to tell if you shared some of the output -- what you got, and what was desired.

Comment: this one is my output Mahindra and Mahindra Financia..
4.8
2.4
Tata Motors
5.0
2.6

Comment: but i want what in the table format

Comment: column.get(i).getText() when you do the println gives you a row at a time? So you get like 5 of them including the header and footer? Or do you get just one long line? That column.get(j) looks like it should be .get(i), but I understand you need to split it.

Comment: ya it gives  output in one long line

Comment: anybody plz help me

Comment: so you want Mahindra and Mahindra in row 1 column 1, 4.8 in column 2, 2,4 in column 3, and then start a new row?

Comment: your locator was not finding me anything (granted I was working in protractor). Instead I got everything in one string as by.id('f1') and getText. Then I did a split using the '/n' and got a 45 item array. Elements 0, 1, 2 are your row one cells, 3, 4, 5 row 2, and 6, 7, 8 row 3. Then you get a 1, which is not the name of a company, and you can stop there.

Comment: @Jeremy Kahan plz show me ur code.because in my case it didnt print anything by using id

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1a1ZvtJ1UwYgDcb9eHxjgmlaHK6BTs-ChifhLo_u3JbE/edit?usp=sharing has my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be with your for loop structure. A couple of notes, first, on some observations.
You need a high implicit wait here because the site is slow to load the findings.
Your rows xpath finds nothing, but your column xpath works, even though it did not when I ported to Protactor.
I am sketching an alternative using locator by id "f1" and splitting the resulting text, but it turns out that is equivalent to what your xpath "column" finds.
The key here is to know when a new row begins and when the items are no longer really data you want. Rows start when the index is a multiple of 3, since each row has 3 fields (a name and 2 numbers). Stuff about which we do not care begins with the number 1. I did not write code to put the data in Excel, but I indicated where you would.
Here is my code (yours will vary slightly because of where your chrome driver or whichever is located, as well as because you have the Excel sheet pieces):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ShonaDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "bin/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(
            "https://careernavigator.naukri.com/sales-executive-retail-careers-in-mahindra-and-mahindra-financial-services-15731");
    /// the row xpath that ws once here found nothing
    List<WebElement> column = driver.findElements(
            By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and (@dy=4 or @dy='3.5')]"));
    int spreadSheetRowNum = 0;
    int spreadSheetColumnNum = 0;
    WebElement f1 = driver.findElement(By.id("f1"));
    for (int i = 0; i < column.size(); i++) {
        if (column.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            // reached end of meaningful fields
            break;
        }
        if (i % 3 == 0) {// start of new row
            spreadSheetRowNum++;
            System.out.println("here create row: " + spreadSheetRowNum);
            spreadSheetColumnNum = 1;// assuming excel column A is column 1
        } else {
            spreadSheetColumnNum++;
        }

        System.out.println("for column list " + i + " text is:");
        System.out.println(column.get(i).getText());
        System.out.println("write it to row " + spreadSheetRowNum + " column " + spreadSheetColumnNum);
    }

    String[] f1Arr = f1.getText().split("\n");
    System.out.println("if you prefer to use the f1 array, its contents are:");
    for (int i = 0; i < f1Arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("f1[" + i + "] = " + f1Arr[i]);
    }
    driver.close();
}
}
```

and here is the output I get indicating what is there and what you need to do at the various steps:

```
here create row: 1
for column list 0 text is:
Mahindra and Mahindra Financia..
write it to row 1 column 1
for column list 1 text is:
4.8
write it to row 1 column 2
for column list 2 text is:
2.4
write it to row 1 column 3
here create row: 2
for column list 3 text is:
Tata Motors
write it to row 2 column 1
for column list 4 text is:
5.0
write it to row 2 column 2
for column list 5 text is:
2.6
write it to row 2 column 3
here create row: 3
for column list 6 text is:
Mahindra and Mahindra
write it to row 3 column 1
for column list 7 text is:
4.6
write it to row 3 column 2
for column list 8 text is:
2.9
write it to row 3 column 3
if you prefer to use the f1 array, its contents are:
f1[0] = Mahindra and Mahindra Financia..
f1[1] = 4.8
f1[2] = 2.4
f1[3] = Tata Motors
f1[4] = 5.0
f1[5] = 2.6
f1[6] = Mahindra and Mahindra
f1[7] = 4.6
f1[8] = 2.9
f1[9] = 1
f1[10] = 1
f1[11] = 2
f1[12] = 2
f1[13] = 3
f1[14] = 3
f1[15] = 4
f1[16] = 4
f1[17] = 5
f1[18] = 5
f1[19] = 6
f1[20] = 6
f1[21] = 7
f1[22] = 7
f1[23] = 8
f1[24] = 8
f1[25] = Avg.Exp
f1[26] = Avg.Sal
f1[27] = In lacs
f1[28] = Avg.Exp
f1[29] = Avg.Sal
f1[30] = In lacs
f1[31] = Top Companies
f1[32] = Top Companies
f1[33] = Top Companies
f1[34] = Top Companies
f1[35] = 1.6
f1[36] = 4.9
f1[37] = 2.4
f1[38] = 1.6
f1[39] = 7.0
f1[40] = 2.6
f1[41] = 1.3
f1[42] = 7.2
f1[43] = 2.9
f1[44] = View 22 more Companies.
```